# Event vs ViewChild when parent needs information about child

Tags: angular

i have several simple form components which have to be validated in the parent component. This means I need to pass formGroups to the parent and I can achieve this by using events or the view child functionality. What is the better approach for passing a formGroup from a child to a parent?

I got told that I shouldn't pass formGroup from child to parent at all but instead to it the other way around, why is that?

here is simple demonstration of what i am trying; https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjnfws

Comment: how are your "simple form components" implemented? do they take a formcontrol as input or do they implement `ControlValueAccessor` or do you use `ngModel`? what kind of validation do you have to do on parent? is it a cross-field validation? do you have a current implementation? if yes can you show us your code please? so that we can have a better understanding of your issue. thanks.

Comment: I am using neither. It's reactive forms. I created a demo on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjnfws .. there will be 50 + form components and 50+ parent components. Parent components hold several form components. Depending on the parent..a form is validated differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion; considering you are going to have 50+ of them; you should keep your "simple form components" as simple as possible and idempotent. this will make your components simple, understandable, reusable, having single and well defined responsibility where all these will result in easier test-ability.

one more important reason to keep them simple is that; they will have different validations when used in different parents. this almost makes it a necessity to make them isolated from any logic as possible. as a result of this; beyond having `FormGroups` and passing it to the parent somehow (eventemitter or viewchild) they shouldn't have a `FormGroup` at all! because when they have `FormGroup` or `FormControl` defined within themselves, you ll also need to set validation logic for those within parent components. instead you should define `FormGroup` and `FormControl`s in parent and child form components must take their `FormControls` as `@Input()`s. such as;

```js
export class Form1Component {
  @Input() firstNameFC: FormControl;
  @Input() lastNameFC: FormControl;
}
```

```html
<h2>Form 1: </h2>

<div>
  <label>First Name: </label>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="firstNameFC">

  <label>Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="lastNameFC">
</div>
```

your parent components should handle creation logic of `FormGroup`s and `FormControl`s along with their validation logic. with this approach you will gain fine control over your application logic at a single point as well as test-ability.

```js
export class ParentComponent {
  public parentFG: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.parentFG = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ["", Validators.required /** control level validators */],
      lastName: [""],
      school: [""],
      address: [""],
    }, {
      validators: [addressSchoolValidator /** group level validators */]
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<form1 [firstNameFC]="parentFG.get('firstName')" [lastNameFC]="parentFG.get('lastName')"></form1>

<form2 [schoolFC]="parentFG.get('school')" [addressFC]="parentFG.get('address')"></form2>
```

here is a demo for above concepts >>> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewel8g

additionally; in your example you also created a separate submit component. within the context of that example i find it unnecessary. submit logic does also belong to parent component.

however, if you have such a use case that requires multiple parent components to be combined and submitted all together, then it makes sense. in this case, submit logic needs to be handled in a grandparent component that has parent components as its children.

at this point you will face with your actual question; "What is the better approach for passing a formGroup from a child to a parent?"

in my stackblitz example above i used `ViewChild` to gather parent components and i prefer it to event emitting for a couple of reasons;

1. it gives fine grained control over forms.
2. it would be good to define required functionality (with regard to formGroup) as a public api in parent forms and expose only those api/methods to outside world and keep formGroup and validation related logics totally isolated from outside.
3. easier mocking for testing :) yes, testing again... :)
4. it is somehow declarative and makes code easier to understand.

all these are fundamentally opinion based, however; i faced with an almost same situation in one of my previous projects. i did extensive research back on those times and i re-designed another colleagues implementation from scratch, later then i also changed my design one more time :D and i came up with pretty much the same solution i explained above.

i hope these shed some light on to your way...

Comment: the "problem" I have with your solution is that my formComponents can and will also be used as standalone components (sometimes) and there I will need the formGroup in the child.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) object

> I got told that I shouldn't pass formGroup from child to parent at all

It's a little bit strange